# How do I know if the determinant is positive?

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

I have the following problem.

Let $ A = \begin{pmatrix}a&b&c&d\\-b&a&d&-c\\-c&-d&a&b\\-d&c&-b&a\end{pmatrix}$

Find $\det(A)$.

I calculated $$AA^T = \begin{pmatrix}a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2&0&0&0\\0&a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2&0&0\\0&0&a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2&0\\0&0&0&a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2\end{pmatrix}$$ and got that $\det(A)^2 = (a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2)^4 \implies \det(A)=\pm(a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2)^2$

But I don't know how to determine the sign of the $\det(A)$. I want to do it without calculating the determinant in a different way

Comment: Squares are always positive numbers (or zero if you are squaring 0).

Comment: @FrancisAdams OP wants to know why he can be sure that no negative sign needs to be added in his last step.

Comment: Multiplying elements on principal diagonal, you get $a^4$ which indicates determinant has positive sign.

Comment: $A$ can be expressed as a sum $B + aI$, where $B$ is anti symmetric. Thus $B$ has purely imaginary eigenvalues, occurring in conjugate/additive inverse pairs. Adding $aI$ to $B$ means the eigenvalues of $A$ will be complex conjugate pairs (with real part $a$), the products of which are non-negative. Thus, $\det A \ge 0$.

Comment: @TheoBendit That should be an answer.

Comment: Let $B$ be the matrix $A$ with the last two rows interchanged.  Then $BB^T = AA^T$, but $\det(A) = -\det(B)$

Comment: You are trying to prove that something is >0 by calculating its square. I don't see how this can get you want you want.

Comment: @Blitzer The point is to compute $\det A$. Computing $\det (AA^\top)$ is easier, but it only narrows down the possible value of $\det A$ to two possibilities. Proving that $\det A \ge 0$ allows us to narrow it to one solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the determinant is the sum of 4! terms, one of which is $a^4$, so we choose the + sign, not the - sign.

alternatively, if we don't know the Leibniz formula, sub a=1 and b=c=d=0, then A is the identity matrix, so $\det(A)=1$, so we choose the + sign.

Comment: Neither of these is really a (complete) rigorous argument. For the former one, you would probably need to say something more about the algebraic nature of the determinant, and for the other one, something about the continuity of the sign as $a,b,c,d$ change.

Comment: @tomasz Even before you calculate anything, it's obviously a homogeneous quartic.